# Problems with Collatz C++ code

Tags: python, c++, linux

I am solving a problem, although I already solved (after a long while) I wanted to find out what was wrong with my implementation.
I programmed my solution in both C++ and Python in Windows. I was trying working with codeskulptor for my Python and it gave me some a TIMELIMITERROR. I switched to C++ language and it gave me some weird errors. I booted up my virtual machine so that I tried to find out why my C++ code failed (I used BCC32 from Borland). I could detect long int number generated by the Collatz sequence that could make my program crash. Under Linux, I got almost the same error, although I could see under Linux, the program runs and could manipulated very well long numbers (using g++ compiler).
Working under Linux, I could use the same Python program I developed for windows and it worked straightforward. I want to know why C++ fails both on Windows and Linux.

```
in Python:

def Collatz(num):
    temp = []
    temp.append(num)
    while num> 1:
        num = num%2==0 and num/2 or num*3+1
        temp.append(num)
    return temp

in C++:

vector<unsigned long> collatz(int num)
{
    vector<unsigned long> intList;
    intList.push_back(num);
    while(num>1)
    {
        if (num%2==0) num /=2;
    else num=num*3+1;
    intList.push_back(num);
    }
    return intList;
}
```

These two piece of codes are the functions only:

the strange thing is that both codes works well calculating the sequence for 13 or 999999. But for example C++ fails to calculate the sequence for 837799... maybe it has something to do with the vector container size??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `num` is an `int`, and you get an overflow after the element `991661525` in the Collatz series for 837799 (all operations are done with the `int`, so you overflow when multiplying `991661525*3+1` in `num=num*3+1`;). Change `num` to `unsigned long` in the function definition

```
vector<unsigned long> collatz(unsigned long num)
```

and it will work!

Comment: yeah! what a fool for not checking on that too... I changed the vector declaration and didn't check on the num variable... thanks guy